# Make search box preselected when initiating message move

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, design, room-owner

As a room owner, you can move messages to another chat room.  When you do that, a box where you can search for a suitable target room is displayed.

[image: Screen shot: Selecting "move messages"]

(In more detail, when you select "move messages" from the "room" dropdown, you first select the messages you want to move, then click "relocate" to proceed to select a room. You are now in the "Move posts" pseudo-dialog.)

The problem with this is that by default (at least in Chrome) there is nothing useful you can do until you first click in the text box in this dialog.

[image: Screen shot: Move to where? Usability problem]

This is a minor annoyance, but also a glaring usability bug which should be easy to fix.  When this dialog comes up, the text box **should already be selected,** so that you can type the name of the target room *without* first clicking there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, that makes sense; deploying fix currently. Thanks for the feedback.